# Return Component from function in render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to return a component from another file in the render function. The function in question is AccessibleTable.

If I return the function directly in the render it's possible, like so:

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header onLogout={this.onLogout.bind(this)}/>
            <div>
                {this.getInfo()}
                <div style={{"height": "275px"}}> </div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                    <button className="bg-gray-100 border-4 border-light-blue-300 hover:border-yellow-500" onClick={this.setSelectedView}
                    >Sstuff</button>
                    <button className="bg-gray-100 border-4 border-light-blue-300 hover:border-yellow-500">More stuff</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <AccessibleTable />
        </div>
        );
}
```

If I do like this instead I get the error

```
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

in render:

```
{this.selectedView}
```

function:

```
selectedView(){
    return <AccessibleTable />;
}
```

AccessibleTable:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650,
  },
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
];

export default function AcccessibleTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="caption table">
        <caption>A basic table example with a caption</caption>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

How do I return this component from a function?
Thank you!

Comment: Show the code for <AccessibleTable />

Comment: Try replacing `{this.selectedView}` with `<this.selectedView/>`

Comment: I have added AccessibleTable and I'll try replacing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

As the error suggests, `selectedView` is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). Consequently, it needs to be *called* to use its product.

Replacing `{this.selectedView}` with `{this.selectedView()}` or `<this.selectedView/>` will result in its underlying JSX being returned and rendered.